# Prove that the termwise product of two null sequences is null?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm not really sure how to choose a suitable $N_i$ relative to the $\epsilon$ for each sequence $x_n$ and $y_n$. I was wondering if somebody could suggest a method to go about this?

Comment: Try using $\sqrt{\epsilon}$ for each sequence (to get $N_x, N_y$) and see how to go from there.

Comment: What if it were only one null sequence?  So the trick here is to "work toward $\sqrt{\epsilon}$" where you ordinarity would "work toward $\epsilon$".

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Since $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to 0$, there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_n|<1$ whenever $n\ge m$. And $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to 0$ as well, so for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $m_\epsilon\ge m$ such that $|y_n|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon$; what can you say about $|x_ny_n|$ when $n\ge m_\epsilon$?